# Get users and groups that have access to Azure resource

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-cli

I have a resource named `devtest`. I want to get list from `IAM -> Role assignments` blade using `azure cli` or `REST API`:

[image]

How to retrieve that information (`group-id`, `display name` etc) in programmatically way? Is it possible to get list of users and groups that have access to resource?

For example, using `graph` im allowed to get groups that signed user belongs to:

```js
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups
Request Body:
{
    "securityEnabledOnly": true
}

Response:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(Edm.String)",
    "value": [
        // group ids here
    ]
}
```

But how to do something similar for resource and get list of users and groups that have role in that resource?

EDIT:

When we go to `Role Assignments` blade, `Azure` calls endpoint:

```js
POST https://graph.windows.net/{subscriptionId}/getObjectsByObjectIds

Request body:
{ "objectIds":[ "bunch unknown ids here" ],"includeDirectoryObjectReferences":true }
```

And i am getting response like:

[image]

That is related for what i am seeing in `Role assignments` tab, but not all positions are returned. In this responses we dont have information about `role`, how to dig into them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below cmdlets, to list all the role assignments of a resource & their respective groups (if the object type of the role assignment is other than User it wont give you any output).

**Here is the Script:**

```
 connect-azuread  # Manadatory to authenticate with azuread & to further run Get-azureadusermembership cmdlet
$rbac=Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName '<RgName>' -ResourceName '<ResourceName>' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults' | Where-Object -Property ObjectType -EQ User| select -Property SignInName,ObjectId,RoleDefinitionName
Write-output $rbac
foreach($item in $rbac)
{
    Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $item.ObjectId | select -Property *
}
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me, how i can find `REST` calls related to your PS functions ?

Comment: try adding the `-Debug` flag to this cmdlet in the above shared script  ``Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName '<rgName>' -ResourceName '<resourceName>' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults' -Debug | Where-Object -Property ObjectType -EQ User| select -Property SignInName,ObjectId,RoleDefinitionName ``  in the output you will be able to see to which REST API this cmdlet is trying to call for execution

Comment: Im playing with your example, it seems like it works pretty okay but could you tell me, how to get `Users` and `Groups` in the same time?